# rosdep gives wrong home-brew packages on OSX

Tags: rosdep, ros-groovy, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get some strange package dependencies from rosdep on OSX. I don't think the suggested **ros/groovy/geometry_experimental** or **ros/groovy/rqt_common_plugins** are valid homebrew packages. Is this a bug?

```
[kevin@tardis ros_catkin_ws]$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y -s
WARNING: Metapackage "common_msgs" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "diagnostics" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "driver_common" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "geometry" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "geometry_experimental" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "image_common" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "image_pipeline" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "image_transport_plugins" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "kdl" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "nodelet_core" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "orocos_kinematics_dynamics" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
WARNING: Metapackage "vision_opencv" must buildtool_depend on catkin.
#[homebrew] Installation commands:
  brew install pyside
  brew install ros/groovy/moveit_ros
  brew install pyqwt
  brew install ros/groovy/geometry_experimental
  brew install pyqt
  brew install tango-icon-theme
  brew install ros/groovy/rqt_common_plugins
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61715/rosdep-gives-wrong-home-brew-packages-on-osx/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2013-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a bug, you have something which depends on packages which are not in your local workspace, i.e. in the `src` folder.

For example, `brew install ros/groovy/moveit_ros` is in there because one of the packages in your workspace depends on `moveit_ros` but `moveit_ros` is not also in your workspace.

Since you need `moveit_ros` and it's not in the workspace, then `rosdep` will try to get it from your package manager, in this case Homebrew. Since we don't have autogenerated formulae for Homebrew yet that won't work. So your choices are to ignore this and hand pick out the other dependencies you need from Homebrew which actually exist OR you can add these missing packages to your local workspace.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-04-29**:
OK ... good to know. I looked at the rosdep documentation, but I didn't find anything that described this behavior. Maybe it should be documented somewhere, unless I missed it.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-29**:
There should probably be some documentation in the wiki somewhere, but this was sort of thrown together for Groovy, and no one has had cycles to improve it or document it. Though `rosdep --help` covers the functionality of the options.